# calculate industry average of variable NetMargin by date (DT)

Tags: sas

```
data work.smallmarket;
set work.market;
where country=Nigeria;
NetMargin=profit2/Rev2;
keep Product# NetMargin DT;
run;
```

Question 1: How can i calculate an industry average NetMargin by date (DT) across all products bearing in mind that not all products will have any data? i.e. no data is not the same as 0.

Question 2: How can I calculate a moving industry average for NetMargin?

Comment: General rules, ask 1 question at a time.  Try something first, and show your work.  We'll help but we're not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

> Question 1:

```
proc sort data= smallmarket; by date_var; run;

proc means data=smallmarket noprint; 
    by createdportaldate;
    output out= by_date
    mean(NetMargin)= 
    ;
run;
```

> Question 2:

If you have access, you could use **Proc expand**, if not, then you can find a worked example at: 
 http://support.sas.com/kb/25/027.html

Edit: found better example: 
https://communities.sas.com/t5/Base-SAS-Programming/Calculate-moving-average-by-group/td-p/296267?nobounce